# Encrypt web.config and disallow to decrypt it on target machine

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config

Is it possible to encrypt the web.config before deployment and distribute it to the target machine without the possibility to decrypt it?

We want to hide the connection string so that the administrator cannot see the con string.

Comment: If the target can't decrypt it, how is it supposed to know what's in it?

Comment: If your code can decrypt, an admin with access to your code and environment can also decrypt it.  It is fundamentally impossible to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt configuration, see here for a full walkthrough:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky(v=vs.100).aspx

Of course, the target machine will still have to decrypt it one way or another, but I assume you just mean them opening up Web.config in say Notepad and having a jolly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can encrypting the Connection Strings section in Web.Config file.

You need to follow the following steps:

1.Open Visual Studio Command Prompt You will need to open the Visual Studio Command Prompt from the Start Menu => Programs => Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 => Visual Studio Tools => Visual Studio Command Prompt.

2.Encrypting the Connection Strings section in Web.Config using aspnet_regiis.exe tool
In order to encrypt the ConnectionString section in the Web.Config file, we will need to use the aspnet_regiis.exe tool.

Syntax:

aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" ""

Example:

aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" "D:\Sai\Projects\MyTestWebsite".

You can refer to this document for full information: https://microsoftdotnetsolutions.blogspot.com/2018/11/encrypt-and-decrypt-of-connection.html